# How to access table data with javascript

Tags: javascript, database, web-applications

I am starting to plan out a web app that calculates certain dimensions of piping components depending on what size and thickness of pipe used (basically, the length of pipe supports that are welded to the pipe). The data I will need to access will be in a table such as this (see pic). This is only a section of the table. It is actually quite large, encompassing all commonly used pipe sizes. My question is what is the best way to access this data? Should I learn how to use js local storage or should I investige how to use a database language and incorporate that into my javascript? Or something else? I'm not a js master by any means... just looking for advice on what direction to focus my research/learning to best accomplish my app
[image: .]

Comment: In my opinion you should not do that in the client on frontend, especially if it's big table. It should be done/processed in the backend. And when it is processed you just fetch the data with JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. What are you suggesting I use for that? PHP? something else? I'm sure I can do it... I just need to know what to research.

Comment: You can do it with PHP, Java, Ruby there are a lot. If you have no previous knowledge I would go with PHP or Ruby on Rails. Java is better but you need more time to learn it. I think you can even use Node.js which is JavaScript for the backend.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could benefit from learning how to make databases. However it might be easier just to store that in a JSON file and use JS to parse it. Generally speaking I would use DBs for storing vast amounts of data securely (like usernames and passwords, user posts etc) but I do believe every web developer should be versed in front and back end processes.

If you want to learn more about how JS interacts with the backend, check out  [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started). Or if you are interested in JS servers, check out [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) and  [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/what-is-mongodb)  (which stores data similiar to how JSON is formatted).

Also as some of the comments have stated, PHP is a great tool for interacting with backend as well.

NOTE: I have very limited experience with web dev, so please feel free to correct me and take everything I have stated with a grain of salt.